# Determining initial and final states from FA diagram

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am new to automata. And learning to find concatenation of two FAs. But this one has confused me
[image: FA 1]
[image: FA 2]

I know how to do concatenation but I am confused that in FA 1, what does **x1** means? Is it mean final state or does it mean both initial and final state because it is on the start?? Just clear me on this that what is initial state and what is final state in **FA 1**? Then I'll take it from here and will be able to do concatenation.

P.S I know that **+-** in a state mean both initial and final state but I don't know about double circle form. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: x1 is just the name of a state. The triangle points at the initial state, and the final states are the ones with the double circle.

Comment: then x1 means both initial and final stage? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case according to what I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your diagrams, a triangle points at the initial state, and double circles indicate final states. Inside the circles you can find the state names, such as `x1`.